# read text file into 2-D array

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I don't know how to calculate the average. I am getting the output I am expecting, except for the average in which I want to enter in a column beside all my other info. Thanks so much to whoever can look at it for me.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public static class Program
{

static void Main()
{
    string file="marks2D.txt";
     string outfile="average.csv";

    StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(file);
    StreamWriter outstream= new StreamWriter(outfile);

    double[,] temp=new double[5,6];
    int num=0;
    double ave=0;


for(int i=0; i<temp.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        double sum=0;
        string line=sr.ReadLine();

        for(int j=0; j<temp.GetLength(1); j++)
        {


          double m=double.Parse(line);
          temp[i,j]=m;
          sum+=m;
          ave = sum/5;

            //temp[i,j]=line;
            outstream.WriteLine(ave);
            outstream.WriteLine("{0,1}", temp[i,j]);
        }


    }
    outstream.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();


    sr.Close();
    outstream.Close();


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared temp as 2-dimensional array.

```
string[,] temp=new string[5,6];
```

You then try to set a value of the 2D array using one index

```
temp[num]=line;
```

This is not possible. For a 2D array, you must use 2 indexes

```
temp[i, j]=line;
```

You are getting the "the name field does not exist in the current context" error because you have commented out the field variable, so it does not exist.

Comment: In my outstream file, how do I declare commas or spaces in between numbers? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare a two-dimensional string array however you are referencing it as single dimensional array inside loop.

Change the line

```
   temp[num]=line;
```

to this:

```
   temp[i,j]=line;
```

Also, you forgot to comment the second outstream.WriteLine, I believe as the variable field is commented out.

```
//outstream.WriteLine(field[num]);
```